# How to set an attribute value using JavascriptExecuter in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to set an `attribute` value for all same kind of `<img>` tag in My website e.g

```
<img src="images/temp/advertisement.png">
```

and i wanted to set `style="display:none"` so I will be able to hide them.

I have tried following method -

```
List<WebElement> element = driver.findElements(By.tagName("img"));

    for(WebElement e:element)
    {

        if(e.getAttribute(src).contains("images/temp/advertisement.png"))
        {
            jse.executeScript("document."+e+".setAttribute('style', 'display: none;')");
        }
 }
```

but getting an error

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
>   unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: SyntaxError:
>   Unexpected token [

Is any one help what is wrong here or what other I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: SyntaxError: Unexpected token [

You are using [`JavascriptExecutor`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html) to execute `javascript` on an `element` but syntactically incorrect, in [`executeScript`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html#executeScript-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) `arguments` will be made available to the JavaScript via the `arguments` magic variable, as if the function were called via `Function.apply` where `arguments` must be a number, a `boolean`, a `String`, `WebElement` etc.

You can try as below :-

```
List<WebElement> element = driver.findElements(By.tagName("img"));

for(WebElement e:element) {    
  if(e.getAttribute("src").contains("images/temp/advertisement.png")){
       jse.executeScript("arguments[0].style.display = 'none'", e);
  }
}
```

Comment: it is not showing error now, but not able to set `style="display:none"` attribute.

Comment: Is it so you will be able to change the attribute value if that attribute present in html for that tag itselt?

Comment: @NarendraRajput Yes, you can update attribute value if it is present already at runtime using this..

Comment: Thanks . Its working . there was timing issue to load the images now its fine

Answer (score 1):

There is problem with that you pass `e` like a object and there is called toString(), so final result is with [] etc... Another way could be something like this:

```
jse.executeScript(
        "var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');" +
        "for(var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) { " +
        "    if (imgs[i].getAttribute('src').indexOf('images/temp/advertisement.png') != -1) { " +
        "       imgs[i].setAttribute('style', 'display: none;');" +
        "    }" +
        "}" );
```

I wrote it without test, so maybe you should edit it ;)

Answer (score 0):

You use `document` to locate the `WebElement`. In your case you already located it. Try

```
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', 'display: none;')", e);
```